# How to create a popup menu on onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So, im trying to create a popup menu with greyed out background when the user clicks on a button in react
My code looks something like this:

```
//ifButtonClicked called another class. this function only runs if another //button is clicked

//some code
export function ifButtonClicked(){
var element = document.createElement("div");
var post_settings = document.createElement("div");
post_settings.className = "post_settings";
post_settings.innerHTML = "button"
post_settings.onclick = (event) => onClickPostSettings(event);
element.append(post_settings);
}

function onClickPostSettings(event){

      //I want it to popup a menu here 
}


*/
```

Since I cant use HTML tags, I am wondering if there any way I can implement a popup menu on onClick. Should i create a new class and call that class inside the onClickPostsettings?

Comment: You can create a component called `PopUp` then you can easily show or hide that component by listening the click event and changing the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a simple `popUpMenu` using state. You can check this to have some idea.

```js
function App() {
  const [popUpMenu, setPopUpMenu] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setPopUpMenu(!popUpMenu)}>
        Menu with Dropdown
      </button>
      {popUpMenu && PopUpMenu()}
    </div>
  );
}

function PopUpMenu() {
  return (
    <ul className="drop-down">
      <li>Menu-item-1</li>
      <li>Menu-item-2</li>
      <li>Menu-item-3</li>
    </ul>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.drop-down {
  list-style: none;
}

.drop-down li {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fbf6f6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!, Im trying to combine my code with ur code. When you said to  create a component called PopUp, Should I do something like this?                                                                    function onClickPostSettings(event, props){
    return (
        <PopupMenu />
    )
}

Comment: You can use a state to store a value and then check if the value is set or null. Your component will be always there but you just need to show it according to the click.

Comment: ahh got it! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
// style.css
ul{
--hide: hidden;
}
ul:hover{
--hide: visible;
}
li{
visibility: var(--hide);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.